# Python numpy list filtering

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

Is it possible to optimize/vectorize the code below? Right now it doesn't seem like a proper way of doing things and it's not very 'pythonish'. The code is intended to work with enormous sets of data so performance is very important.

The idea is to remove all the values and their names which do not occur in both lists.

E.g. The outcome of the code below would be two lists with "name2" and "name4" having values [2,4] and [5,6] respectively.

```
import numpy as np

names1=np.array(["name1","name2","name3","name4"])
names2=np.array(["name2","name4","name5","name6"])

pos1=np.array([1,2,3,4])
pos2=np.array([5,6,7,8])


for entry in names2:
    if not np.any(names1==entry):
        pointer=np.where(names2==entry)
        pos2=np.delete(pos2,pointer)
        names2=np.delete(names2,pointer)

for entry in names1:
    if not np.any(names2==entry):
        pointer=np.where(names1==entry)

        pos1=np.delete(pos1,pointer) 
        names1=np.delete(names1,pointer)
```

Comment: Are you wedded to using `numpy` for this?  This feels more like a `pandas` problem.

Comment: I have no experience with pandas. Any hints appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vectorized answer:

```
import numpy as np

names1=np.array(["name1","name2","name3","name4"])
names2=np.array(["name2","name4","name5","name6"])

pos1=np.array([1,2,3,4])
pos2=np.array([5,6,7,8])

intersection=np.intersect1d(names1,names2)
pointer1=np.argwhere(np.in1d(names1, intersection) == False)
pointer2=np.argwhere(np.in1d(names2, intersection) == False)

pos2=np.delete(pos2,pointer2)
names2=np.delete(names2,pointer2)

pos1=np.delete(pos1,pointer1)
names1=np.delete(names1,pointer1)
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is a straightforward `merge` operation in [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"name": names1, "pos": pos1})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name": names2, "pos": pos2})
>>> df1
    name  pos
0  name1    1
1  name2    2
2  name3    3
3  name4    4
>>> df2
    name  pos
0  name2    5
1  name4    6
2  name5    7
3  name6    8
>>> df1.merge(df2, on="name", suffixes=[1,2])
    name  pos1  pos2
0  name2     2     5
1  name4     4     6
```